# Hide Model in Django Admin according to value in DB

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to hide a model in the django admin interface according to a value
in the database.

My first solution was to add this to the `ready()` handler of the app:

```
    from foo.models import MyModel
    if MyModel.objects.filter(...).exists():
        from foo.models import ModelToHide
        admin.site.unregister(ModelToHide)
```

Above solutions works ... except:

This fails in CI.

If `CI` builds a new system from scratch, the database table of `MyModel` does not exist yet:

Any hints how to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the solution lies in [this bit of the admin logic](https://github.com/django/django/blob/da3df5b878d96ef37dcff1377ccbd097b80776d7/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L422-L427).

So you would provide a custom `ModelAdmin` for your model, and then override `get_model_perms` to do something like this in `admin.py`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        # Do your check here - if you want to hide the model from the admin then...
         return {
             'add': False,
             'change': False,
             'delete': False,
         }

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Django checks to see if any of these perms are `True` - if not then it will hide the model from view.